# Calculation-Bug in Safari? Repeating the same calculation several times changes it's result

Tags: javascript, math, safari

I'm observing strange behavior in Safari:

I have a function that should calculate the midi note from a frequency. This works fine when I do this only a few times, but when I do the same calculation a few 1000 times, the result becomes wrong in the end.

This is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/38tzLsjL/
(it might be necessary to run the example several times until the error happens)

The function is this:

```
var calcMidiNoteFromFrequency = function (frequency) {
    var notRoundedMidi = 12 * (Math.log(frequency / 440) / Math.log(2));
    var roundedMidi = Math.round(notRoundedMidi) + 69;

    return {notRoundedMidi:notRoundedMidi, roundedMidi:roundedMidi};
}
```

When I call this function a few thousand times with the same parameter it changes its result. 
`notRoundedMidi` will stay correct, but `roundedMidi` changes to a wrong value.
If I remove `+ 69` the error disappears...

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Verified I get the same behaviour.

Comment: Good to know. Did you see that also in Safari?

Comment: Yes safari on a Mac Book Pro. I think a bug report on https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/ is in order.

Comment: I've just downloaded the latest nightly build, and I can't seem to reproduce the bug on that. I suspect it might be fixed.

Comment: It indeed looks like a browser bug... did you find a concrete bug-report on bugzilla? I didn't find one that seems to fit. Could you post the Report-ID, if you found one?

Comment: I was able to fix that by moving the + 69 into the parameter of Math.round() like `Math.round(notRoundedMidi + 69)`... but as long as I don't really know what I'm fixing here this is just a hack, that could always break again...